# Failed login attempts by an unknown user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, logins

I have an alert in SQL Server that notifies me when there are failed login attempts. This alert began to arrive during the early morning every about 3 minutes (see screenshot).

[image: Profiler capture]

This login attempt will never be successful because that user does not even exist.

When investigating the ClientProcessId from the Resource Monitor I see that it corresponds to Powershell.exe that when capturing the event and looking at the process it appears as Terminated.

Could it be that they are trying to access my database? It catches my attention that it doesn't come with another username.

My database continues to work correctly and when I check with sp_whoIsActive I don't see any suspicious activity

I'm going to be performing a failover at a time of less use to rule out that it's something that has gone "crazy" but I would like to know if this has happened to anyone or how I can find out who is running that powershell.

I have also checked the users connected remotely and there was no one other than my account.

The user who is trying to log in (rs-em7-svc) appears as if he were local to the server and I understand that this type of user can refer to Reporting Services, however, I do not even have reporting services installed on that server.

Does anyone have any idea how I can continue investigating?

Answer (score 3):

Well, after investigating the local users of the server I see that this user is one used by the rackspace tool that is our service provider. So I already contacted them to inform me why this service is trying to enter our database.